# Scala XML template skipping elements

Tags: xml, scala

I have this code:

```
val list1 = Seq("One", "Two", "Three")
val list2 = Seq("Four", "Five", "Six")

val xml = <Root>
  {
    list1.map { item =>
      <Item>{item}</Item>
    }
    list2.map { item =>
      <Item>{item}</Item>
    }
  }
</Root>
```

It is creating an XML document like this:

```
<Root>
  <Item>Four</Item>
  <Item>Five</Item>
  <Item>Six</Item>
</Root>
```

But my intention is to generate this document:

```
<Root>
  <Item>One</Item>
  <Item>Two</Item>
  <Item>Three</Item>
  <Item>Four</Item>
  <Item>Five</Item>
  <Item>Six</Item>
</Root>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it appears that a {} block in an XML template can only return one NodeSeq value. So, I need to wrap each iteration in a separate {}.

```
val list1 = Seq("One", "Two", "Three")
val list2 = Seq("Four", "Five", "Six")

val xml = <Root>
  {
    list1.map { item =>
      <Item>{item}</Item>
    }
  }
  {
    list2.map { item =>
      <Item>{item}</Item>
    }
  }
</Root>
```

Comment: Dont forget to tick your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try merging the 2 lists before `map`ping on it

```
val list1 = Seq("One", "Two", "Three")
val list2 = Seq("Four", "Five", "Six")

val xml = <Root>
  {
    (list1 ++ list2).map { item =>
      <Item>{item}</Item>
    }
  }
</Root>
```

I believe what is happening in your case is that when evaluating a block, Scala returns the value of the last expression. In your case

```
list2.map { item =>
   <Item>{item}</Item>
}
```

Comment: The code I posted is a simplified version of a more complex case. The lists contain two different types and I can't just merge them.